# Add new parameter to header format in theorem style

Tags: amsthm

I’m using the amsthm package to have theorem environment. I would like to display something like `Axiom 1 = BA 1 (Some text)` where BA is the reference to axioms of another paper.

So I tried this:

```
  {\topsep}% measure of space to leave above the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {\topsep}% measure of space to leave below the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {\itshape}% name of font to use in the body of the theorem
  {0pt}% measure of space to indent
  {\bfseries}% name of head font
  {.}% punctuation between head and body
  { }% space after theorem head; " " = normal interword space
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2} = BA \thmnumber{#4}\thmnote{ (#3)}}
```

but I got the error `Illegal parameter number in definition of \thmhead@theoremdd.`

Is it possible to achieve something like I want? If yes, how?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What's your intended syntax? I guess something like `\begin{axiom}{1}[Some text]`. Is it so?

Comment: Thanks! Yes that’s a syntax I thought about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add parameters like that.

I suggest something along these lines:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{axiom}
  {\topsep}% measure of space to leave above the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {\topsep}% measure of space to leave below the theorem. E.g.: 3pt
  {\itshape}% name of font to use in the body of the theorem
  {0pt}% measure of space to indent
  {\bfseries}% name of head font
  {.}% punctuation between head and body
  { }% space after theorem head; " " = normal interword space
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2\extraref}\thmnote{ (#3)}}

\theoremstyle{axiom}
\newtheorem{axiominner}{Axiom}
\newcommand{\extraref}{}
\newenvironment{axiom}[1]
 {%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  \else
    \renewcommand{\extraref}{ = BA #1}% if argument is empty, add nothing
  \fi
  \begin{axiominner}}
 {\end{axiominner}}

\begin{document}

\begin{axiom}{1}[Some text]
This is an axiom.
\end{axiom}

\begin{axiom}{1}
This is an axiom.
\end{axiom}

\begin{axiom}{}[Some text]
This is an axiom.
\end{axiom}

\begin{axiom}{}
This is an axiom.
\end{axiom}

\end{document}
```

If you want an external reference, add the number in the *mandatory* argument to `axiom`. This would (locally) redefine the macro `\extraref` to print the desired output.

[image]